# VC++ (.Net) 2010 Draw Graphic To A Window

Tags: c++-cli

How can I draw a .png file to a certain window like for an example notepad?

```
HWND hWnd = FindWindow(0, "Untitled - Notepad");

void DrawTohWnd()
{
     Image^ newImage = Image::FromFile("smile.png");
     //Draw newImage to Window (Notepad)...
     //...
}
```

Comment: This requires injecting a DLL into the process so you can subclass the window and intercept the paint message.  You cannot write code like that in C++/CLI, it requires native code.  Very hard to get right.

Comment: @HansPassant: You're right about DLL injection.  But managed code can do window subclassing just fine.  See `NativeWindow::AssignHandle`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use the [`Graphics::DrawImage` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage.aspx) and pass in your `Image` object (along with any other desired parameters specifying drawing options).

But that requires you to have an instance of the `Graphics` class corresponding to your window (`HWND`). You can get one by calling the [`Graphics::FromHwnd` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromhwnd.aspx).

Do be careful with the code you have written, though. Searching for windows by their caption is an inherently fragile method—windows change titles often.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I just quickly typed up the code just to give you guys a better understand of what my goal is.